# DAX Search a string for multiple values

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I need to create a new DAX column that will search a string from another column in the same table. It will search for any of the values in a 2nd table, and return True if any of those values are found. Simplified example:

Let's say I have a table named Sentences with 1 column:

```
Sentences
Col1
----------------
"The aardvark admitted it was wrong"
"The attractive peanut farmer graded the term paper"
"The awning was too tall to touch"
```

And another table named FindTheseWords with a list of values

```
FindTheseWords 
Col1
----------------
peanut
aardvark
```

I'll be creating Col2 in the Sentences table, which should return

```
Sentences
Col1                                                    Col2
----------------------------------------------------    ------------------------
"The aardvark admitted it was wrong"                    TRUE
"The attractive peanut farmer graded the term paper"    TRUE
"The awning was too tall to touch"                      FALSE
```

The list of FindTheseWords is actually pretty long, so I can't just hardcode them and use an OR. I need to reference the table. I don't care about spaces, so a sentence with "peanuts" would also return true.

I've seen a good implementation of this in M, but the performance of my load took a pretty good hit, so I'm hoping to find a DAX option for a new column.
The M Solution, for reference: [How to search multiple strings in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316657/how-to-search-multiple-strings-in-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

fact table

```
| Column1                                              |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| The aardvark admitted it was   wrong                 |
| The attractive peanut farmer   graded the term paper |
| The awning was too tall to   touch                   |
| This is  text string                                 |
| Tester is needed                                     |
```

sentence table

```
| Column1    |
|------------|
| attractive |
| peanut     |
| aardvark   |
| Tester     |
```

Calculated column

```
Column =
VAR _1 =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( 'fact', "newColumn", SUBSTITUTE ( 'fact'[Column1], " ", "|" ) )
VAR _2 =
    GENERATE (
        _1,
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            GENERATESERIES ( 1, PATHLENGTH ( [newColumn] ) ),
            "Words", PATHITEM ( [newColumn], [Value], TEXT )
        )
    )
VAR _3 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        _2,
        "test", CONTAINS ( VALUES ( sentence[Column1] ), sentence[Column1], [Words] )
    )
VAR _4 =
    DISTINCT (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            FILTER ( _3, [test] = TRUE ),
            "Column1", [Column1] & "",
            "test", [test] & ""
        )
    )
VAR _5 =
    DISTINCT (
        SELECTCOLUMNS (
            FILTER ( _3, [test] = FALSE ),
            "Column1", [Column1] & "",
            "test", [test] & ""
        )
    )
VAR _7 =
    FILTER ( _5, [Column1] = MAXX ( _4, [Column1] ) )
VAR _8 =
    UNION ( _4, _7 )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER ( _8, [Column1] = CALCULATE ( MAX ( 'fact'[Column1] ) ) ),
        [test]
    )
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: I think I'm following most of that. Since I'm using Power Pivot in Excel, I won't be able to use GENERATESERIES. Is there a substitute you'd recommend?

Comment: Please correctly tag to attract the correct answerer, it saves a lot of time. You tagged PowerBI in your original question though. I am not an excel user, so sorry if it does not work.