# Simplying Text.Contains in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

This is not a call for assistance, but more for some advice. I have a fully functioning code below and wondered if it could be streamlined.

```
= Table.AddColumn(
#"Renamed Columns", 
"Company Name", 
each if Text.Length([Person Surname]) > 20 or 
Text.Contains([Person Surname], "Ltd") or 
Text.Contains([Person Surname], "Limited") or 
Text.Contains([Person Surname], "Llp") then [Person Surname]
 else "")
```

Namingly I am looking at the `text.contains` parameter. I was wondering if, rather than having 3 separate queries I could just use 1 with something like {"Ltd", "Limited", "LLP"}. This was should I want to add any further parameters down the line I could simply add them into the brace's.

Comment: Look here. You need to use `if Text.Length([Person Surname]) > 20 or List.AnyTrue(List.Transform({"Ltd","Limited","Llp"}, (x) => Text.Contains([Person Surname], x))) = true then [Person Surname] else null` source: **[How to search multiple strings in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35324537/8162520)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, IMO the nested `List.Transform()` is redundant if we can do it in one sweep though. Either way, like in many other instances; There is more than one way to skin a cat!

Comment: @JvdV Sir absolutely agreed. Understood the use `List.MatchesAny`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [List.MatchesAny](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-matchesany) function:

[image]

```
if Text.Length([Person Surname]) > 20 or List.MatchesAny({"Ltd","Limited","Llp"}, (s)=> Text.Contains([Person Surname], s)) then [Person Surname] else null
```

Comment: This is perfect, will so much easier to manage going forward should anymore parameters need adding.

Comment: I am trying to replicate this process to remove the values from `Person Surname` after they have been passed over to the new Company Name Column. However when my makes all of the Surnames an Error.

    `= Table.TransformColumns(
    #"Added Custom", 
    {{"Person Surname",
    each if Text.Length(_)>20 or 
    List.MatchesAny({"Ltd","Limited","Llp","T/a","Plc"}, (s)=> Text.Contains([Person 
    Surname], s)) then "" 
    else _}})`